# How to change android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton color programatically

Tags: android, background, floating-action-button, android-support-design

I have a *`android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton`* with `app:backgroundTint="#3399ff"` and `android:backgroundTint="@color/white"`.

I use `DrawableCompat.setTintList(DrawableCompat.wrap(floatingActionButton.getContentBackground()), androidBackgroundTintColor);`

to change  `android:backgroundTint="@color/white"` but i haven't figured out how to change `app:backgroundTint="#3399ff"`...

**Would you happen to know?**

Please note its **app:backgroundTint** and not **android:backgroundTint**.

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
fab.setBackgroundTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getApplicationContext(), R.color.purple_200));
```